# Ngx Translate Compiler, not compile

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

I am trying to compile a response of request in CustomCompiler but I faced a problem. After I compile data I return my compiled variable but, when I use the translate filter, I still see the old translate texts.

My loader factory and custom compiler code:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
 return new TranslateHttpLoader(http,'http://localhost:8100/getWebMultilanguages?lang=');
}

export class CustomCompiler implements TranslateCompiler{

  compile(a:string,b:string) {
    console.log('compile',a,b)
    return '{}';
  }

  compileTranslations(translation:any,b:string){
    return Object.keys(translation).reduce((acc: any, key) => {
      acc[key] = translation[key] + '|compiled';
      return acc;
    }, {});
    //return {MOJO:'DEMO'}
  }

}
```

Translate Module is imported as :

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide:TranslateLoader,
        useFactory:HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps:[HttpClient]
      },
      compiler:{
        useClass:CustomCompiler,
        provide:TranslateCompiler
      }
    })
```

Html :

```
{{'MOJO'|translate}} //this return only DEMO, not DEMO|compiled
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but when navigating to another page and back again it works. When reloading the page it's still "DEMO"

Comment: @bjorkblom when component  renders html, ngx-translate bind translation result before compileTranslations function runs. So  you should hide translations until compile function will be finished or use a customloader class

Comment: How do I do that? Do you got an example or documentation for that?